# Python service crashed and I can not find log for that in centos

Tags: python, ssl, crash, centos, systemd

I have written a simple webserver in python and run it in centos, and created it with systemd service.

It uses ssl module and `ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)` and

```
if PORT==443:
                context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
                context.load_cert_chain(certfile="cert.crt", keyfile="key.key")
                with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as bindsocket:
                        bindsocket.bind((HOST, PORT))
                        bindsocket.listen(3000)
                        bindsocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
                        while True:            
                                newsocket, fromaddr = bindsocket.accept()
                                newsocket.settimeout(10)
                                try:    
                                        connstream = context.wrap_socket(newsocket, server_side=True)  
                                        connstream.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
                                        threading.Thread(target = handleSocket,args = (connstream,fromaddr,)).start()
                                except:
                                        try:    
                                                connstream.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
                                                connstream.close()
                                        except:
                                                pass
        else:
                with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:                         
                        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
                        s.bind((HOST, PORT))
                        s.listen(3000)
                        while True:                
                                conn, addr = s.accept()            
                                conn.settimeout(10)            
                                threading.Thread(target = handleSocket,args = (conn,addr,)).start()
```

for using ssl part.

I don't know why it sometimes closes.

I've downloaded centos log file and found these logs, but noting gave me any useful

> Aug 25 20:35:28 localhost kernel: python3.7[28448]: segfault at
>   7f3752864400 ip 00007f376046bfa0 sp 00007f375162cec8 error 4 in
>   libc-2.17.so[7f3760320000+1c2000]
>
> Aug 25 20:35:28 localhost python3.7:
>   Total time: 0.09245038032531738
>
> Aug 25 20:35:28 localhost systemd:
>   cdnpython-new-ssl.service: main process exited, code=killed,
>   status=11/SEGV
>
> Aug 25 20:35:28 localhost systemd: Unit
>   cdnpython-new-ssl.service entered failed state.
>
> Aug 25 20:35:28
>   localhost systemd: cdnpython-new-ssl.service failed.

Comment: Can you post your full python script? Which version of SSL and Centos/Python are you using? You need to provide information for us to replicate.